# Voltage detected on output SSR while in "OPEN" state

Tags: solid-state-relay

I have an SSR relay ( FOTEK SSR-25 DA ), it has load terminals marked (1) and (2).

In normal "open" position there's no connectivity between 1 and 2 - no current whatsoever.

The moment I apply 120VAC to the terminal 1 - I can immediately see that there's 120VAC on terminal 2, in the "open" position ( still no connectivity - I test with a multimeter ).

I reviewed a few manuals like https://www.ia.omron.com/data_pdf/guide/18/ssr_tg_e_9_2.pdf - yet I don't see how "2" can possibly get any voltage there from "1".

Is that relay defective or am I missing something?

Comment: Look at page 6 of your linked manual under "leakage current".

Comment: **Counterfeit Fotek SSRs**

It appears that you are considering Fotek SSRs. Read this first: 
[UL warns of solid state relay with counterfeit UL Recognition Mark (Release 13PN-52)](http://www.ul.com/newsroom/publicnotices/ul-warns-of-solid-state-relay-with-counterfeit-ul-recognition-mark-release-13pn-52/).

See also Big Clive's [Teardown of an eBay 25A Solid State Relay (SSR)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxEhxjvifyY&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: @Transistor Your first link just redirects to UL's main news page.

Comment: @Hearth, hmmm, they've taken it down. Here's another: https://protosupplies.com/inferior-counterfeit-fotek-ssr-25-solid-state-relays-on-the-market/.

Comment: Consider the effect of capacitance (typically ~nF?), relative to your meter's impedance (typically 10M).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try reading measuring it with a load connected and see what you get. SSR's don't isolate (disconnect) the output, rather, they are in "high-impedance" state when they are off. Your DMM has such a high input impedance that it will be able to measure the potential from the other load terminal. This is all in contrast to an electromechanical "clicky" relay where off truly means disconnected or "open".